# creating json array dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to dynamically add JSON to an array:

```
let output = [];
let input = [{"Packages":"111","Weight":"2","Id":"row-0"},
             {"Number__c":"123","Packages":"123","Id":"row-1"}]
let tmp;
let f = 5;
let s = f.toString();
tmp = {f : input};
output.push(tmp);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

I want to have the key "f" in this case be represented as 5 in the output but it comes through as "f"

console:

```
[{"f":[
{"Packages":"111","Weight":"2","Id":"row-0"},
{"Number__c":"123","Packages":"123","Id":"row-1"}]
}]
```

gotta be possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON construction to get the desired result as:

```
let input = [{"Packages":"111","Weight":"2","Id":"row-0"},
         {"Number__c":"123","Packages":"123","Id":"row-1"}];
let f = 5;
let output = [];
var obj = {};
obj[f] = input;
output.push(obj);
```

This can be solved with other different techniques as well, refer this question: [Add dynamic key, value pairs to JavaScript array or hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398583/1023542)

Comment: Thanks, but I need 5 to be dynamic. I am getting it from a variable

Comment: Updated the answer with some psuedo code

Comment: Awesome! That did it. Thanks guys!